# my software repository wont update correctly

Tags: command-line, upgrade, repository, software-sources

After I upgraded my Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 my repository that I had added them to `/etc/apt/source.list.d` directory in Ubuntu 16.04 wont update when I update my repository for example by `sudo apt update` command, please tell me if you know how it works.

Comment: Please add some more details. What exactly are you trying to acheive, what have you done so far, and what errors are you seeing?

Comment: @ahmad some error message output would help

Comment: @George there is no error message when i update my repository ,I just know that my repository that i added them in /etc/apt/source.list.d  when i used Ubuntu 16.04  wont update correctly in Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: @Zanna ,For example i use Atom ide , i added a repository in /etc/apt/source.list.d when i installed Atom on Ubuntu 16.04 , But now this repository wont check when i use "sudo apt update" command in Ubuntu 16.10 .

Comment: @ahmad, sorry to ask again but since you say you know then tell us how you came to that conclusion so we can help from there. There must be something you observed to reach that point please share that.

Comment: @ahmad, As I remember,  Release upgrade disable PPA's and 3rd party repositories sources. You can edit & enable them from `software-properties-gtk`

Comment: @user.dz ,thanks for your answer ,just a question : i should edit them from "other software" in  "software-properties-gtk" ?

Comment: @ahmad, yes these packages are usually disabled when you upgrade and you have to manually enable them again, and if any is causing problems just disable from there too.

Comment: @ahmad, I wrote that as an answer.  You can flag it as accepted if  it worked for you. Otherwise, you could comment if I miss any thing.

Comment: @user.dz ,how should i flag as accepted? , it dosent have this item:(

Comment: @ahmad, Check AskUbuntu quick intro at [about] (see that green check sign to the right in a circle). BTW, you can choose either my answer or George's one  you are totally free.  Also you can vote up when you reach >= 15 rep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As I remember, Release upgrade disable PPA's and 3rd party repositories sources.

  You can edit & enable them from `software-properties-gtk`.
- > i should edit them from "other software" in "software-properties-gtk" ? – ahmad (OP)

  Yes, you can edit them there.

  1. Some repository have same package for multiple releases, don't need any edit, just enable them.
  2. Some others need to be edited `xenial` to `yakkety` if they support yakkety. Then enable them.
  3. If yakkety is not supported, leave it disabled to skip the related error messages till you get some update from the related project. (I miss this point, Thank you [George](https://askubuntu.com/users/459561/george))

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. go to systems settings
2. select `software and updates`
3. go to `other software` tab
4. there enable the repositories that you want.